# What's the difference with Python statements ending with ;?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

What's the difference with Python statements ending with ; and those does not?

Comment: Those ending in `;` are usually written by people who don't realize it isn't necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is really no difference. Python ends a line of code at the end of the logical line, or when it encounters `;`

The only advantage to using `;` is that you can stack multiple logical lines into one physical line. For example (in python3):

```
import sys

for i in range(10):
    print(i, end=' '); sys.stdout.flush()
```

That said, this is terrible coding style, so don't ever do it

Answer (score 2):

Semicolons serve the same purpose as the newline character. It is really just bad style to use a semicolon, often from people coming from languages where lines require it.